# Microsoft office customization installer error

Tags: .net, deployment, vsto, outlook-addin, netsuite

- running Windows 7
- .net version 4.6.1
- this happens when i try to load an add in called netsuite for outlook
- the error say the system cannot find the file specified but even when i navigate to the file and launch from there i get the same error.
- i have tried uninstalling and reintalling the app
- I have tried running the .net framework repair utility
- i have tried copying the file from a computer that didn't have the issue

none of this has worked.

[Error window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrzDy.png)

detals from the error window:

Name: 
From: %AppData%/Local/Celigo/Applications/NetSuite for outlook/Celigo.NetSuiteAddIn.vsto

************** Exception Text **************
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
   at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IsolationInterop.GetUserStore(UInt32 Flags, IntPtr hToken, Guid& riid)
   at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IsolationInterop.GetUserStore()
   at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore..ctor(ComponentStoreType storeType, SubscriptionStore subStore)
   at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore..ctor(String deployPath, String tempPath, ComponentStoreType storeType)
   at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.get_CurrentUser()
   at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager..ctor(Uri deploymentSource, Boolean isUpdate, Boolean isConfirmed, DownloadOptions downloadOptions, AsyncOperation optionalAsyncOp)
   at System.Deployment.Application.InPlaceHostingManager..ctor(Uri deploymentManifest, Boolean launchInHostProcess)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.IPHMProxy..ctor(Uri uri)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.get_Proxy()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.GetManifests(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()

If you need any more details let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that variables `APPDATA` and `LOCALAPPDATA` are no longer defined for that userprofile.

**To verify:**

open a command line, type `set`. These variables will not be listed.

**FIX:**

create a new userprofile.